# How to send message to telegram as ```code````

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

[Sending the output of Prettytable to Telegram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750744/sending-the-output-of-prettytable-to-telegram?noredirect=1#comment121530765_68750744)

This question is a followup to an earlier question. The code which i have is this:

```
import telegram
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def send_msg(text):
    token = "*******:**************"
    chat_id = "***********"
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)
    
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)
        
myTable = PrettyTable(["Student Name", "Class", "Section", "Percentage"])
  
myTable.add_row(["Leanord", "X", "B", "91.2 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Penny", "X", "C", "63.5 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Howard", "X", "A", "90.23 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Bernadette", "X", "D", "92.7 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Sheldon", "X", "A", "98.2 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Raj", "X", "B", "88.1 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Amy", "X", "B", "95.0 %"])
table_txt = myTable.get_string()
with open('output.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(table_txt)
new_list = []
with open("output.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
     send_msg(file.read())
```

The problem is that the message which is sent looks like this:

```
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
| Student Name | Class | Section | Percentage |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
|   Leanord    |   X   |    B    |   91.2 %   |
|    Penny     |   X   |    C    |   63.5 %   |
|    Howard    |   X   |    A    |  90.23 %   |
|  Bernadette  |   X   |    D    |   92.7 %   |
|   Sheldon    |   X   |    A    |   98.2 %   |
|     Raj      |   X   |    B    |   88.1 %   |
|     Amy      |   X   |    B    |   95.0 %   |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
```

But when the message received in telegram looks like this:

[image]

How can i fix this? Telegram lets you send messages in `code` whereby i guess it would preserve the format. How can i send this message in   format?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have already solved it yourself: you used three backticks in the title of your question. In Markdown (including here on SO), you can put three backticks around a block of code, and that makes it use the **code block** formatting.

````
```
this is inside a code block
```
````

You can just add a line containing the three backticks in front and back of your text:

````py
backticked_text = "```\n" + text + "\n```"
````

Comment: your solution worked but i guess prettytable just doesn't hold the form in telegram

Comment: This works, but only on desktop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVbTo.png -- on mobile, it does this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LzLP.jpg

Comment: make sure to remove formatting of your code text. for example, if your code currently has a non default, font it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

Trying to send formatted tables via Telegram is a lost cause. Even when sending the table in monospace, you can't control the line breaks. As already observed by Danya02, the line breaks depend on the client, the device (i.e. the display width), the font, font size etc. If you want to make sure that the user sees a nicely formatted table, send it as PDF or image.

Answer (score 2):

One should paste a code inside ``` block **without** formatting. If you use a Telegram messenger, paste your code using **Cmd + Shift + V** to remove a formatting.

Comment: Thanks. The "non-formatted" is very important. I wondered why it sometimes worked and sometimes not

Answer (score 0):

Telegram supports markdown (atleast for code). You can add ``` at the start and end of your text (first and last line), and it should work out

Comment: No, it does not work

Comment: markdown does work if you use `"parse_mode": "MarkdownV2"`